# Change Color of ActiveX Command Button with Macro

Tags: vba, excel, activex

As a part of a spreadsheet I'm making, I want a macro to change the color of an ActiveX button.  Right now I have the button change colors when it is clicked.  I want it to change back to the original color when a separate macro is run.

Any thoughts are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: So whats the problem in doing it? If you have done it once, do it from another macro

Comment: I should've clarified.  The macro that works is a private sub.  I'm trying to get it to work on a sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the Button is white:
Macro1:

```
Sheet(n).CommandButton1.BackColor = 'something
```

Macro2:

```
Sheet(n).CommandButton1.BackColor = &H00FFFFFF&
```

Shouldn't this be the only thing you have to do?
[(More)](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1717-excel-change-color-of-button.html)

Comment: This is the line I'm using

      CommandButton1.BackColor = 12713922
I get the "Object Required" error when I run it.

Comment: Try `Sheet1.CommandButton1.Backcolor =  'Something` Works for me. Sorry forgot about the `Sheet1.` part before

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tmpSO()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Obj As OLEObject

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each Obj In Sh.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(Obj.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
            Debug.Print Obj.Name
            If Obj.Object.BackColor = -2147483633 Then
                Obj.Object.BackColor = 6740479
            Else
                Obj.Object.BackColor = -2147483633
            End If
        End If
    Next Obj
Next Sh

End Sub
```

Note, that the `.Name` resides directly on the `.OLEObject` while the `.BackColor` is a sub-element of `.OLEObject.Object`.

The above code will toggle all buttons background color between the greyish (default) color and an orange color.

Let me know if you have any questions.